# Remove drop shadow from jQuery fancybox 1.3.4

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is there a way to remove the drop shadow effect?

I deleted the drop shadow images but the shadow is still there...

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css just remove or alter the following lines:

```
#fancybox-bg-n {
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-x.png');
}

#fancybox-bg-ne {
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -162px;
}

#fancybox-bg-e {
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-y.png');
    background-position: -20px 0px;
}

#fancybox-bg-se {
    bottom: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -182px; 
}

#fancybox-bg-s {
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-x.png');
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}

#fancybox-bg-sw {
    bottom: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -142px;
}

#fancybox-bg-w {
    top: 0;
    left: -20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('fancybox-y.png');
}

#fancybox-bg-nw {
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    background-image: url('fancybox.png');
    background-position: -40px -122px;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I overlooked this css file I guess ;)

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget the IE CSS. Everything below this line must also be removed

> .fancybox-ie .fancybox-bg { background: transparent !important; }

Answer (score 4):

I spent like 30 minutes to find how to do that in FancyBox 2.0 and up. Though this question is for FancyBox 1 series, I though it would be nice to save some time for people looking for it on FancyBox 2.0 series.

Delete these declaration around Line# 41 in `sources/jquery.fancybox.css` file

```
.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the jquery.fancybox css file, 
add "display:none;" 
to .fancybox-bg{...}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the lib css, you can just add this your css after the fancybox css lib include

> ```
> .fancybox-bg {
>   display: none;
> }
> ```