# Fancybox Iframe - Show only the inner content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

When I use fancybox to load an external url, It is showing inside another `div` with border and background as white. I want to display only the content, which is in the URL. No need to show the outer box, including drop shadow and close button. How can I make it like this ?
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For removing drop shadows you can look [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5184862/2613728).

and for hiding close button, fancybox has option itself, look for showCloseButton in [fancybox api](http://fancybox.net/api) ,of course you can use `display:none` for `.fancybox-close` to get the result.

Comment: you misread the question, the OP is using fancybox v2.x so none of your suggestions will work.